# Get the exact value from Rad Month Year Picker

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, telerik

I have a sort of weird question: I have a RadMonthYearPicker and I set the format for 'yyyy-MM-dd'. The date shows up nicely on the control but when I try to get that date to send to a stored procedure, the value returns as 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Here's the code for the control:

```
    <telerik:RadMonthYearPicker ID="RadMonthYearPicker1" Runat="server" Culture="en-US" HiddenInputTitleAttibute="Visually hidden input created for functionality purposes.">
    <DateInput DisplayDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" DateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" LabelWidth="40%">
    <EmptyMessageStyle Resize="None"></EmptyMessageStyle>
```

And here's the C#:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime? selectedDate = RadMonthYearPicker1.SelectedDate;
        string date = "";

        if (selectedDate != null)
        {
            date = selectedDate.Value.ToString();
            Label3.Text = date;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

This what happens:
[Wrong Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26TZb.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer culture is set to "dd/MM/yyyy". Use this:

```
DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: Thanks it now shows as it was supposed to, just like God intended :P